# Aren't migrations supposed to be not deleted?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, database-migration, sequelize-cli

I'm using Sequelize for my PostgreSQL in a node app.

Let me elaborate my question. **I had two migrations** - *one* that created a table and the *other* that added a column to it.

I can see those migration entries in the `SequelizeMeta` table in my psql but the issue is when I go and delete one of those migration files from my project, the corresponding entry doesn't go away.

I can understand that I have to run `sequelize` commands thereafter for the conflict to appear but it still doesn't show anything when I try to run the `sequelize` commands.

For instance, after having run both of the migrations and then deleting the second one, I ran `sequelize db:migrate:undo:all` to only see that it was able to correctly run the *revert* for the **first CREATE table migration** only.

> It totally ignored the entry of the second migration from the `SequelizeMeta` table.

When I ran `db:migrate`, it also didn't throw me any errors when I hoped it would look for the second migration file. It just ran the first one.

P.S. Where is the sync between migrations and `SequelizeMeta` table then? Or `sequelize-meta` for that matter?

Here's an [open issue](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/214).

Comment: Removing one migration that already has been run on a production database is typically not something that happens, unless you're deleting many old migrations. Perhaps you can explain why you feel you want to remove this one migration so that we can better explain how your task could be accomplished?

Comment: Please read my question title again - yes, I understand and am totally against it. But in the event of "deleting older migrations", why isn't the SequelizeMeta table updated when there is an undo migration run subsequent to the deletion of the migration file? Only during the `db:migrate` does it go ahead with updating the table... The table feels more like a log file to me!